# How do I protect a specific page from being viewing with out login in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I want to protect a specific page in a controller from access only if the user is logged in it is the add.html page for adding questions, the index.html page is used to show questions that are asked but I want to to remain public. How do I make it that when someone clicks on ask a question from index that it checks for login and if not logged in has flash notice saying you must login and redirect at same time to login page.

New error on index page:

```
NoMethodError in Car#index

Showing app/views/car/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h2>Current List of Open Questions</h2>
2: <dl>
3: <% @car.each do |car| %>
4:   <dd>
5:     <%= car.name %><br />
6:     <%= car.description %><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a before_filter to ensure the user is logged in before running the protected actions. Here's a simple example - naturally your implementation details depend on how you rolled your own auth.

In your application controller (assuming you're storing the id of the current logged in user in session[:user_id]):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
  def ensure_login
    if session[:user_id].blank?
      flash[:notice] = 'You must be logged in to use this part of the site.'
      begin
        redirect_to :back
      rescue
        redirect_to '/'
      end
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

and then in the controller where you are limiting access:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_login, :only => [ :add ]
end
```

Comment: i have it working now but i used before_filter :authenticate, :except => :index from brain but get the new error on my index page

Comment: yeah I have it working now thanks guys for all the help and I will need more help in a few hours, got to get this web application created in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a login system already, you could set a before filter to only authenticate on the actions your desire.

```
before_filter :authenticate, :except => :index
```

Comment: when I add that line I get this error: NoMethodError in CarController#add

undefined method `authenticate' for #<CarController:0x72b3b08>
RAILS_ROOT: C:/Users/Jatinder/BitNami RubyStack projects/mercedes_mod 2

Comment: The name of the "authenticate" method depends on your login system - use whatever method you have that checks for a logged in user and redirects to or displays the login form if there isn't one.

Comment: @jeremy ok I changed it to protect and added the def protect etc and it is working but now when I go to my index page I get an error please view the updated question to see this new error

Comment: It looks like your @car is not set to anything.  Should it be @cars?  It is being populated in your controller before you render the index page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the login code yourself, you should look into gems like Devise, Authlogic and Restful authentication - (listed in decreasing order of stuff you have to do to get things up and running)

Comment: No I already have log in function and log out etc I just need it so that they have to log in I have the pages for log in and log out already